# show content not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a show more & show less. When executing this code I get and error "Show content not defined" can't pick up. What  am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function HideContent(hide) {
        document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "none";
    }
    function ShowContent(show) {
        document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "list-item";
    }
    function ReverseDisplay(hide) {
        if (document.getElementById("hide").style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
        else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
    }
    </script>

    heading<br/>
    <a href="javascript:ShowContent(show)" >
    Show
     </a>
    <div id="hide" style="display:none;">
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <a href="javascript:HideContent(hide)">
    hide
    </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use inline JavaScript because as the code scales, it becomes less and less maintainable. Instead you should use the DOM API methods to select the element and use the [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method to assign an event listener function.

However, the reason you are getting this error is because your are using variables in your JavaScript which have not been defined. This causes an error and stops the script, which means that ShowContent and HideContent won't be initialized and therefore when you try to use those functions they won't exist, throwing an error.

```js
var hidd = document.getElementById("hidden");
var hide = document.getElementById("hide");
var show = document.getElementById("show");

show.addEventListener('click', function(){
    hidd.style.display = '';
    show.style.display = 'none';
}, false);

hide.addEventListener('click', function(){
    hidd.style.display = 'none';
    show.style.display = '';
}, false);
```

```html
<a id="show" href="#">Show</a>
<div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
    <a id="hide" href="#">hide</a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There no error showing anymore but the the hidden content is not showing.

Comment: I'm not developing a website, i'm developing a mobile app using visual studio and apache cordova. They require me to code in HTML,javascript, CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The variables you are passing into the function, `show`, and `hide` are not defined. Also, `onclick` is better for running JavaScript.

```
<a href="#" onclick="ShowContent()" >
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wke2dwqw/2/)

I don't recommend using inline code and would put everything in a script tag

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.querySelector('#showContent').onclick = function () {
            ShowContent();
        }
    };
</script>

<a id="showContent" href="#">Show</a>
```

Comment: please don't encourage inline javascript

Comment: @royhowie It's what the OP wants but I'll make a not of that